# What is the formal definition of the wording `non-deducible`

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20

[temp.names#6](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#6)

> A template-id is valid if
>
> > - there are at most as many arguments as there are parameters or a parameter is a template parameter pack ([temp.variadic]),
> > - there is an argument for each **non-deducible** non-pack parameter that does not have a default template-argument,
> > - each template-argument matches the corresponding template-parameter ([temp.arg]),
> > - substitution of each template argument into the following template parameters (if any) succeeds, and
> > - if the template-id is non-dependent, the associated constraints are satisfied as specified in the next paragraph.

> A simple-template-id shall be valid unless it names a function template specialization ([temp.deduct]).

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U>
struct Test{};
int main(){
  using type = Test<int>;
}
```

Consider the above code, in this case, is the second template parameter `U` `non-deducible`? It seems there is no formal terminology in the standard that interprets what is `non-deducible`. There's only a definition for `non-deduced context`, However I think they are not the same things. So how do I understand the wording `non-deducible`?  Is it unclear using such wording for which there's no formally definition?

#### Question

1. `Test<int>` is an invalid template-id, which bullet does it violate in the above list?
2. what `non-deducible` refer to?
3. Is the template parameter that does not participate in template argument deduction may be called `non-deducible`?

Comment: Where is your quote from?  I'm having trouble finding it

Comment: @NathanOliver [https://www.google.com/search?q="A+template-id+is+valid+if"](https://www.google.com/search?q="A+template-id+is+valid+if")

Comment: @NathanOliver Modified the question.

Comment: The english language definition of "deducible" is "able to be deduced".  The prefix "non-` means negation/opposite.   So "non-deducible" means "unable to be deduced".    The word "deduce" is a verb with meanings "to derive as a conclusion from something assumed or known" or "to trace the derivation of".   In context of the quote, the simplest meaning would be something like "unable to be derived".

Comment: @Peter You mean that `non-deducible` comprise the `non-deduced context` and something that can't be derived, Right? And In my example, `U` is a `non-deducible` template parameter?

Comment: @jackX: Where are you getting "deduced context" from? Nobody said anything about contexts here.

Comment: @NicolBolas My meaning is the template parameter that appear within `non-deduced` context can be called `non-deducible`?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by "non-deduced context".   Things that are known or  assumed are not deduced - they are inputs (or constraints) to the process of deduction.   Deductions - and other actions taken based on those deductions - are products of the deduction process.

Comment: @Peter My meaning is these template parameters that only appear in non-deduced context may be `non-deducible`?

Answer (score 4):

This is just English. "Deducible" means "able to be deduced". C++ has a [well-defined process for deducing template arguments](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct). If an argument is "deducible", then it is an argument for which this deduction process succeeds and is thus "able to be deduced".

"Non-deducible" simply means "not deducible". And therefore "not able to be deduced". And thus this template argument deduction process fails.

So it's saying "there is an argument for each non-pack parameter whose argument can not be deduced via template deduction processes". There's nothing unclear about that.

Comment: Template argument deduction is performed for these template parameter that participate in template argument deduction . The template parameter `U` does not participate such process. So Is it non-deducible?

Comment: The key point here is, the `Test<int>` is not necessary to perform template argument deduction. It's just a case that template argument explicitly specified for the template. Even if the template argument deduction is performed for such `template-id`, however the second template parameter `U` does not participate such process. `In most cases, the types, templates, and non-type values that are used to compose P participate in template argument deduction. `

Comment: In short, Do you think the template parameter that does not participate in template argument deduction may be called `non-deducible`?

Comment: @jackX This what is written in the answer.

Comment: @Oliv It seems to all template parameter of primary class template are all `non-deducible`, what can `deducible` are these type that appears in function template or those types that would be re-written to function template(template parameters of a class partial specialization).

Comment: @jackX Indeed for class. For function template, only template parameter that apear in the argument type can be deduced as long as after transformation of the function argument type, the form of the argument type is one of the form listed in [temp.deduc.type]

Comment: @Oliv  Through studying [temp.deduct]. It all says template arguments deduction for these `parameter types` that comprised by template parameters, which origined from transformed function type, even though the deduction for class partial specialization, as if it's a parameter type from hypothetical function template. For a type that refer to template-id, These template arguments either be explicitly specified or instantiated from default arguments, So for a simple template-id that names a class template name, Its template parameters are non-deducible.

Comment: @jackX http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#8 and the paragraph bellow

Comment: constructor deduction guides can make class template arguments deducible, no?

Comment: @Oliv The link you cite here describes what forms the deduction can deduce for it. However  these `Type` is specified by these template parameter which are function template's, i.e.  These types was derived from function types of  function templates. That is, the deduction process deduce template arguments for these template parameter to form `P` that is compatible with actual type `A`. If you name a `type` through `template-id`, the only way to form such specialization is to explicitly specified these template arguments for such template-name.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont  constructor deduction guides is a `constructor` which follows by `template-id`, such `template-id` comprised by template-argument-list which consists of template parameters that are `constructor's`, To use such `Constructor` to deduce template arguments for these template parameter which are constructor's (constructor is a special function).

Comment: @Oliv There's no way to form a `type` of `template-id` which name is template-name without explicitly specifying template arguments , except that `constructor deduction guides`, however as I said in above comment, such `constructor` is a special function template to deduce template arguments for its template parameters.

Comment: @jackX Honestly I am struggling to understand what you write, because of your english...

Comment: @Oliv I don't think my writing has any problem. It is clear. In short, template argument deduction only occur with functions(these template parameters of template functions participate in template argument deduction, which composed as `P`).

Comment: @jackX And wherever a placeholder may be used http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.auto.deduct

Comment: @jackX Never agree with yourself! What do you think of this sentence: "It all says template arguments deduction for these parameter types that comprised by template parameters, which origined from transformed function type, even though the deduction for class partial specialization, as if it's a parameter type from hypothetical function template." For exemple "that" introduce a clause that must have a verb, idem for "even though"

Comment: @Oliv The sentence after `that` is used to describe `these parameter types`, i.e, These parameter types are comprised by template parameters. what's wrong with this sentence?

Comment: @Oliv  I have re-written what I want to say:  what the standard says about template arguments deduction are all based on these parameter types which specified by template parameters, which originated from transformed function type, even though the deduction for class partial specialization, The behavior is as if it's a parameter type from hypothetical function template. I.E, the deduction process occurs with function template. An other context that will result in deduction is the appearance of `placeholder` specifier as you supplemented in the above comment.

Comment: @Oliv So whenever obtained a specialization referred by a `template-id` which name is a `class template`, we only can **explicitly specified template arguments** for its corresponding template parameter due to its template parameter is non-deducible. As for template argument deduction guide, It use the `template constructor` to make it to obtain template arguments for these template parameter of its class in essence. Do you agree? Now, Are these sentence easy to understand?

Comment: @jackX No they are not... First sentence: In a template-id that names a class template specialization, template arguments are eitheir explicitly given or provided by a default template argument because they are non-deductible

Comment: @Oliv Yes,  the way of supplying default arguments is absent. Since these template parameters of such template is non-deducible, hence the way to supply template arguments is either explicitly specified or present default arguments. Otherwise such template-id is valid. I only talk about how a template-id would be invalid.

Comment: Second sentence, it tooks me tile to understand that you mean that temolzte argulent throw deduction guide can be considered as a direct deduction of template arguments is it goes throw template function call argument deduction. This looks like an opinion

Comment: @Oliv  It seems to exist typo in your last comment. I don't know what you mean